# Add line breaks in cell to 1000 rows of data

Tags: excel, macros, vba

I am currently using the below code to add a line break to cell data in column C and copy it to column K. I need to apply line breaks to a range of data. I have 1000 rows of data in column C.
Any help will be much appreciated.

```
Sub Macro
    Dim Stem As Variant
    Stem = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets ("Sheet1").Range("C2")
    Range ("K2").Select
    Range("K2").FormulaR1C1 = Stem & Chr(10) & ""
End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: try to google "excel vba loop through range" (without quotes) and see if that starts you off in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things:

- Better to early bind your variables than late (better memory
  management, take advantage of intellisense, etc.)
- Usually best
  practice to avoid using "select" if possible.
- Your Stem variable is an object (Range Object) and thus needs to be "Set"

Try this:

```
Sub Macro
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim Stem As Range
    Dim R2 As Range
    Dim Rng as Range

    Set WS = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set Stem = WS.Range("C2", Cells(WS.Range("C2").End(xlDown).Row, WS.Range("C2").Column))
    Set R2 = WS.Range("K2", Cells(Stem.End(xlDown).Row, WS.Range("K2").Column))

    R2.Value = Stem.Value
    'New Code
    For Each Rng In R2
        Rng.Value = Rng.Value & Chr(10) & ""
    Next Rng
    'Old Code: R2.End(xlDown) = R2.End(xlDown) & Chr(10) & ""

End Sub
```

What this does is first sets the worksheet you're using. Then, you set your working range (Stem) using the Range(cell1, cell2) format. Cell1 I defined as "C2". The next expression there is using the Cells() function. It is the VBA equivalent of being in "C2" and hitting Ctl+Down, then seeing what row you're in.

Then, I set your destination range, R2, in a similar manner, but I used the Stem range to determine how large it should be.

Finally, to get an accurate copy your destination range must be the same size as your from range. The .value to .value expression pastes the data. Then, your extra characters are added on to your new data field.

Something to keep in mind with .End(xlDown)... if you have blank rows in the middle of your data it will stop there, not go all the way down to the end. Hope this helps!

**EDIT:** 
The `For Each` loop will go through every range (i.e. cell) in your destination range, R2, and add your new characters. Hope that fits better for you.

Comment: Thanks. This code applied line break only to the last row data in column K.

Comment: That is what it was intended to do based on my understanding of your question. Where specifically did you need the line breaks? I can revise my answer.

Comment: Thanks I need in every cell which has data.

Comment: I modified the code. If you find an answer that works for you, make sure you click the check next to the voting arrows to let people know we have answered your question. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Sub copyAndNewLine()
'copy column C to K
Columns("C").Copy Destination:=Columns("K")

'loop through all cells in K and add new line
For i = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row
    Cells(i, "K").Value = Cells(i, "K").Value & vbCrLf
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: It says run time error 1004 application-defined or object- defined error.

Comment: End sub was excluded from the code, I just copied it into an empty sheet and runs OK, no error even when C is empty. Try and see which line it fails when you run it in step mode from VBA editor (F8).

Also be aware that the code you posted runs till first empty cell, if any cell in your data will be blank it will stop.It might be better to use the for loop from mine as that searches for the last cell in specific column and check the content by IF when you don't want to add new line for empty cell.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all for your answers. I atlas was able to write my first script and got the code to add line break inside the cell.

```
Sub AddLineBreak()
Dim Stem As Variant
Stem = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C2")

Dim i As Integer
i = 2
'this will terminate the loop if an empty cell occurs in the middle of data
Do While Cells(i, "C").Value <> ""
  Cells(i, "K").Value = Cells(i, "C").Value & vbCrLf
  i = i + 1
Loop

End Sub
```